# Find if Active Directory is Enabled/Disabled with Email

Tags: c#, active-directory, userprincipal, principalsearcher

I'm trying to find if a user has an Active Directory account by searching with their email address and checking the Enabled property (if I return Enabled as true - run code, if I return false - run other code, and if the results are null - return false because that email doesn't exist anymore).  When I get to the foreach loop, it has found the user based on their email in *result*, but checking with the if and elses returns *user* as NULL.

```
    public static bool DoesUserExist(string email, string domain)
    {
        var found = false;

        using (PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
        {
            UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(domainContext);
            user.EmailAddress = email;

            PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(user);
            search.QueryFilter = user;

            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = search.FindAll();

            foreach (Principal result in results)
            {
                if (user.Enabled == true)
                {
                    found = false;
                    Helpers.LogMessage("Active Directory Account is Enabled in " + domain + " domain");
                }
                else if (user.Enabled == false)
                {
                    found = true;
                    Helpers.LogMessage("Active Directory User Account is Disabled in " + domain + " domain");   
                }
                else if (user.Enabled == null)
                {
                    found = true;
                    Helpers.LogMessage("No Active Directory Account Found in " + domain + " domain");
                }
            }

            return found;
        }
    }
```

What am I missing to be able to access if the user is Enabled or Disabled in the foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is user has nothing to do with the results of your search or the loop; it is just the template for searching. Also note that if no result is found, you will not enter the loop (`results` will be empty) and so testing for `null` makes no sense. Also, your `found` settings seem to be wrong.

```
if (!results.Any())
    Helpers.LogMessage("No Active Directory Account Found in " + domain + " domain");
else {
    var found = false;

    foreach (UserPrincipal result in results) {
        found = !result.Enabled;
        if (found)
            Helpers.LogMessage("Active Directory User Account is Disabled in " + domain + " domain");   
        else
            Helpers.LogMessage("Active Directory Account is Enabled in " + domain + " domain");
    }
}
```

Comment: You were right about need to use UserPrincipal instead of just Principal!  I'm able to actually check the users now, thank you!  And "found" was in the right spot actually; it would have made more sense if you saw the code that it returns it to.

Comment: Except I don't believe it is possible for `result.Enabled` to be null?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant that it needed to be set within the if and else.  You had moved to outside of that, but still in the foreach.

Comment: I see what you mean. I think I fixed it properly.